iOS: Can I get crash reports from my users if I didn't submit to testflight?
I have a beta group of users in testflight but I forgot to submit my app first to them (submitted directly to al users). It doesn't let me submit the same version to testflight anymore. Will I still receive crash reports from users in my beta testers group even if they didn't get the app via a testflight release?
